# Can I Switch On Asus X555L laptop without battery?

Tags: battery, asus-laptop

My Asus X555LA laptop switched off after draining battery although I was using it plugged in to AC Power. Now when I try to switch on without plugging to AC, I can't and while plugged in to AC,within 2,3 seconds it switch off. As most of the laptop models work fine without battery, I removed the battery and try to switch on, and it does nothing.In order to troubleshoot I would like to know whether I can run this model without the battery. If can, I can assume the issue is not a dead battery, but laptop's charging circuit.

Comment: Asus says you should be able to.....https://www.asus.com/support/FAQ/1014276/

Comment: Thank You for pointing that. But it also says some models can't. That's why I specifically need to know for this model.

Comment: Possibly you have a bad ac adapter, dc plug end that connects to the laptop or a defective dc jack in the laptop.

Comment: Only thing I read in that article was that some batteries were not removable.

Comment: I checked the adapter with a multimeter, It is supposed to give out 19V and it does out little over 19V. So the adapter and the jack works fine, But I can't be sure about the receiving end at the laptop.

Comment: I have the erxact same issue with the Asus 550Z

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The laptop can run without the battery.  This particular model doesn't use as much power as it can accept when charging, as it's not exactly a high-end gaming model.

I would lean toward the laptop itself having issues pulling from the battery, or even the battery itself having gone bad.  Is there any swelling on the battery casing that makes the plastic feel softer and movable?  If so, that battery is now a fire hazard and needs to go.  Otherwise, your problem may be in the internal components of the laptop's power system. If so, it may be cheaper to replace than fix.

Comment: I tried with removing the battery, plugged to AC. But I couldn't switch on. So with what you suggest, is it an issue with the internal power system ?

Comment: Yes.   BTW in a lot of laptops the only thing holding in the power supply connector socket inside the laptop is the solder that connects the wires from the motherboard to it.  Check and make sure the power supply socket isn't off center inside the laptop case.  If it looks like it is a little, a bad connection there can lead to this sort of thing.