# Does Asus X551M can run without a battery?

Tags: laptop, power-supply, battery, asus

I have an Assus X551M laptop.

Without a battery (which is dead) it does start to some degree:

- power diode lights up
- some brief noise from the CD or HDD

but:

- the CPU fan does not start
- the screen does not react at all

The power supply is 19V 1,75A, 33W which does not seem a lot.
From checking on the Internet it says that around 30W is the absolute minimum in general for any laptop.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I Switch On Asus X555L laptop without battery?](https://superuser.com/questions/1312658/can-i-switch-on-asus-x555l-laptop-without-battery)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It does not need a battery to run.

I thought that it is like some Apple laptops that can not run without a battery, but that is not the case.